# How to allow the user to manually add image to image view?

Tags: android, widget, imageview

Long story short, I want the user to add an image after touching the image view on an Android.

Any tips?

Comment: Long answer short, open an image picker, and use the URI or whatever in the response to set the image on the ImageView

Answer (score 0):

implement the image picker to get image from device and set it to imageview.

Ref:
[check this github repo](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker)

[android official photo picker guide](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/04/photo-picker-everywhere.html)

[Article about photo picker](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/photo-picker-in-android-13-with-example-project/)